# Create a bat file to open multiple projects in Visual Studio Code with one click

Tags: windows, batch, batch-file, shortcuts

I created a shortcut for each of my projects in VSCode to speed up the process of opening them:

[image]

But if I select the four shortcuts with the mouse and try to open them with the *ENTER* button, it only opens the `Code A` shortcut, the rest are not opened. So I decided to try another approach.

In the shortcuts properties, the **target** to open each one of them is this:

```
"C:\Users\Computador\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe" "C:\Users\Computador\Desktop\Code A
"C:\Users\Computador\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe" "C:\Users\Computador\Desktop\Code B
"C:\Users\Computador\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe" "C:\Users\Computador\Desktop\Code C
"C:\Users\Computador\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe" "C:\Users\Computador\Desktop\Code D
```

So I've tried creating a *bat file* for that:

Test 1:

```
@echo off

cd "C:\Users\Computador\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\" "C:\Users\Computador\Desktop\Code A
start Code.exe

cd "C:\Users\Computador\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\" "C:\Users\Computador\Desktop\Code B
start Code.exe

cd "C:\Users\Computador\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\" "C:\Users\Computador\Desktop\Code C
start Code.exe

cd "C:\Users\Computador\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\" "C:\Users\Computador\Desktop\Code D
start Code.exe

exit
```

Test 2:

```
@echo off

cd "C:\Users\Computador\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe" "C:\Users\Computador\Desktop\
start Code A

cd "C:\Users\Computador\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe" "C:\Users\Computador\Desktop\
start Code B

cd "C:\Users\Computador\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe" "C:\Users\Computador\Desktop\
start Code C

cd "C:\Users\Computador\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe" "C:\Users\Computador\Desktop\
start Code D

exit
```

I was not successful in any of the two alternatives, how should I proceed to open the four projects at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do in the batch file is:

1. `cd` (change the terminal's directory) to the project directory
2. Start VS Code from there

Seems to me like you are doing the opposite.

Try:

```
@echo off

cd "C:\Users\Computador\Desktop\Code A"
start "" "C:\Users\Computador\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe" .

cd "C:\Users\Computador\Desktop\Code B"
start "" "C:\Users\Computador\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe" .

cd "C:\Users\Computador\Desktop\Code C"
start "" "C:\Users\Computador\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe" .

cd "C:\Users\Computador\Desktop\Code D"
start "" "C:\Users\Computador\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe" .

exit
```